# Bug RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(list.size()-1) in Dialog

Tags: java, android

I have created RecyclerView with list of clients (from 0 till 14). I need maximum down state. For this purpose I am using method RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(14).

When RecyclerView are placing in Activity, I have the good result.

[IMAGE: RecyclerView are placing in Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8a0t.jpg)

And now I am inflating new RecyclerView and put it in Dialog. The Adapter of RecyclerView the same. Method RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(14) give me the bad result (scroll is not set on the 14th position, by the way I can pull it to the down manually):

[IMAGE: Bad result in Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc306.jpg)

Why it happens? I think the problem in parent (Dialog) of RecyclerView. But I don't know what to do.

UPDATED! I think this is a really bug of RecyclerView. Because with ListView is all right (in my case with setSelection(14)).

Answer (score 0):

Because your interaction panel hide the last element. Position your recycler view above the panel.

Comment: Ok. Any ideas for fix?

Comment: Show me the dialog's xml file.

Comment: I create Dialog with AlertDialog.Builder and put the RecyclerView with setView(recyclerView).